# Python .replace() not removing newline character

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make a 'filter' of sorts to remove certain characters from a string.

I want to remove: 
Parenthesis () 
Single Quotes ' 
Commas , 
Newline Characters \n

The code I am using to do this looks like:

```py
i = {
    'content':('\n\nPosh Pantry Boutique',)
}

table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, ")(,'",))
i['content'] = (str(i['content']).translate(table)).replace('\n','')

#for readability, this code can also look like this:
#x = str(i['content'])
#x = x.translate(table)
#x = x.replace('\n','')
#i['content'] = x

print(i['content'])
```

However, the output of this code removes all the characters except the newline character. 
`\n\nPosh Pantry Boutique`

I have tried to use .strip(), to no avail. 
So, what am I doing wrong, or, is there no way to remove these characters?

Comment: The value in your dict isn't a string, it's a tuple (due to that trailing comma inside the parentheses).  When you apply `str()` to a tuple, you get the `repr()` of its elements - which turns unprintable characters into escape sequences.  So there aren't actually any newlines, there are simply backslashes followed by `n`s.  If you actually *wanted* to work with a tuple for some reason, you'd have to use `.replace('\\n`,'')`.

Comment: If you're trying to remove certain characters from the string, you could just use the `filter` function:
`''.join(filter(lambda c: c not in ")(,'\n",YOUR_STRING))`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a single slash.  `\` is an escape character so you need to escape the slash. `\\n` will fix your issue.

Docs for your reference.
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

```
i = {
    'content':('\n\nPosh Pantry Boutique',)
}

table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, ")(,'",))
i['content'] = (str(i['content']).translate(table)).replace('\\n','')

#for readability, this code can also look like this:
#x = str(i['content'])
#x = x.translate(table)
#x = x.replace('\n','')
#i['content'] = x

print(i['content'])
```